# How to read the textfile by command line arguments and print the column by using perl?

Tags: perl

---

How to read the text file using perl command line arguments and print the **third** **column** using perl?

I'm struck with taking input from the command line and printing the required column. Help me to choose the right way to reach the expected output.

**Code which I wrote to take command line input:(`map.pl`)**

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use Getopt::Long 'GetOptions';
my @files=GetOptions(
    'p_file=s' => \my $p_file,
);
print $p_file ? "p_file = $p_file\n" : "p_file\n";
```

**Output I got for above code:**

```
perl map.pl -p_file cat.txt
p_file = cat.txt
```

**cat.txt:(`Input file`)**

```
ADG:YUF:TGH
UIY:POG:YTH
GHJUR:"HJKL:GHKIO
```

**Expected output:**

```
TGH
YTH
GHKIO
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl can automatically read files whose names are provided as command line arguments. The command below should produce your expected output

```
perl -F: -le 'print $F[2]' cat.txt
```

`-F:` turns on `autosplit` mode, sets the field separator to `:`  and loops over lines of input files. `-l` handles line endings during input and output. The code after `e` flag (`'print $F[2]'` prints 3rd field) is executed for each line of file. Find out more by reading `perldoc perlrun`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to read the file and split the lines to get the columns, and print the required column. Here's a demo code snippet, using the **perl -s** switch to parse command line arguments. Run like this **./map.pl -p_file=cat.txt**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s
use strict;
use warnings;
use vars qw[$p_file];

die("You need to pass a filename as argument") unless(defined($p_file));
die("Filename ($p_file) does not exists") unless(-f $p_file);

print "Proceeding to read file : $p_file\n\n";

open(my $fh,'<',$p_file) or die($!);

while(chomp(my $line = <$fh>)) {
        next unless(defined($line) && $line);
        my @cols = split(/:/,$line);
        print $cols[-1],"\n";
}

close($fh);
```

Comment: hi i executed as follows`(perl  map.pl -p_file cat.txt)`.But it returns nothing@Pradeep

Comment: why we are specifying equal to instead of double quotes@Pradeep

Comment: https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node166.html#SECTION001834000000000000000